# How to get image path from another server /host in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two sites, the first one (portal site) when I upload an image it stores the image in the `wwwroot` folder in the second publish (the master site), but when I try to view the image in the portal site I can't.

The image is stored in the database as following:

```
StaticFiles\images/items/restaurant\1cb28510-84e1-40ac-9cf8-343e875fcadb.jpg
```

[the image is shown like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXuTl.png)

The path of the image is like

```
http://....:8814/StaticFiles/images/items/grocery/02ad8fe9-5cdb-4bb9-bf80-cb8b1007184e.jpg
```

but if I want to view it I need to make it like

```
http://....:8813/StaticFiles/images/items/grocery/02ad8fe9-5cdb-4bb9-bf80-cb8b1007184e.jpg
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So you have to change the port number to make it work? What do your F12 debugging tools tell you?

Comment: yes, i need to change the port number , in the incpector the path is like that src="\StaticFiles/images/items/home\100212.jpg"

Comment: How is Razor supposed to know that your image URLs point to a different host? You need to write an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set as below in your first project:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = (c) =>
                {
                    c.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                },
            });
```

Also,you could read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Result:
[image]